# How can I optimize a functional mergesort for large lists

Tags: python, performance, haskell, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to learn functional programming and algorithms at the same time, and Ive implemented a merge sort in Haskell. Then I converted the style into python and run a test on a learning platform, but I get return that it takes too long time to sort a list on a 1000 integers.

Is there a way i can optimize my python code and still keep my functional style or do I have to solve the problem iteratively?

Thanks in advance.

So here is the code I made in Haskell first.

```hs
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] xs = xs
merge ys [] = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | (x <= y) = x : (merge xs (y:ys))
  | otherwise = y : (merge (x:xs) ys)

halve :: [a] -> ([a] , [a])
halve [x] = ([x], [])
halve xs = (take n xs , drop n xs)
        where n = length xs `div` 2

msort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
msort [x] = [x]
msort [] = []
msort xs = merge (msort n) (msort m)
    where (n,m) = halve xs
```

Then I made this code in python based on the Haskell style.

```py
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1002) #This is because the recursion will go 1002 times deep when I have a list on 1000 numbers.
    
def merge(xs,ys):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return ys
    elif len(ys) == 0:
        return xs
    else:
        if xs[0] <= ys[0]:
            return [xs[0]] + merge(xs[1:], ys)
        else:
            return [ys[0]] + merge(xs, ys[1:])

def halve(xs):
    return (xs[:len(xs)//2],xs[len(xs)//2:])

def msort(xss):
    if len(xss) <= 1:
        return xss
    else:
        xs,ys = halve(xss)
        return merge(msort(xs), msort(ys))
```

Is there a smarter way I can optimize the python version and still have a functional style?

Comment: `return [xs[0]] + merge(xs[1:], ys)` this line makes it really slow and I don't think you can optimize it to dezirable speed without making code ugly

Comment: `heapq.merge` is suitable for merging two sorted lists. Don't use recursion in Python if you can help it, especially when the call tree is O(n) in size.

Comment: The recursion in `msort` isn't so bad, as the depth of the call tree is only O(lg n)

Comment: To be really efficient, though, you need to do an in-place merge, so that `halve` doens't need to create two new lists each time.

Comment: @chepner re O(log n), that was my first thought too, but the recursion in `merge` is O(n) though, isn't it?

Comment: @ИльяКузнецов "this line makes it really slow" telling why is that would be very helpful. :) is my guess correct that it will copy the second list whole to append it after the singleton? (thus leading to quadratic behavior)

Comment: @chepner in-place merge seems an overkill, having two arrays, going between them, filling one from the other, switching sides on each step, should be enough.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, doing `merge` recursively is a bad idea in Python. Recursion is expensive and has a configurable-but-hard limit on the depth of the recursion tree. Recursive `msort` with non-recursive `merge` is tolerable, since you need a *really* big list before you hit the stack limit. The suggestion to do an in-place merge is independent of recursion: it stems from the fact that `x[:len(xs)//2]` itself is an O(n) operation, not O(1) like it would be if you were simply getting back a view of the underlying list.

Comment: @chepner would you mind terribly confirming my suspicion (or otherwise) that `[x]+xs` copies `xs` whole while creating its result? (googling didn't help) --- also, why isn't `x[:len(xs)//2]` O(1)? isn't it slicing? I thought it _was_ getting back a view of the underlying list. ---- (in-place merge with 1 array is hard. two arrays are easy and good enough. :) )

Comment: It's a slice, but it has to build a new copy of the last `n/2` characters because lists are mutable. There is a buffer protocol for getting O(1) views, but I don't think it's implemented for lists. `[x] + xs` is a copy for the same reason.

Comment: Your Haskell isn't terribly performant either. `halve` does a lot of extra work. I generally recommend a "bottom up" merge sort for lists. If you want a top-down one, you can halve unstably in a more efficient way, or halve stably somewhat better by taking the length just once and calculating the recursive lengths from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell lists are lazy. `[x] ++ xs` first produces the `x`, and then it produces all the elements in `xs`.

In e.g. Lisp the lists are singly-linked lists and appending them *copies* the first list, so prepending a singleton is an *O(1)* operation.

In Python though the appending copies the *second* list (as confirmed by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) in the comments), i.e. `[x] + xs` will *copy* the whole list `xs` and thus is an *O(n)* operation (where `n` is the length of `xs`).

This means that both your `[xs[0]] + merge(xs[1:], ys)` and `[ys[0]] + merge(xs, ys[1:])` lead to  *quadratic* behavior which you observe as the dramatic slowdown you describe.

Python's equivalent to Haskell's lazy lists is not lists, it's generators, which produce their elements one by one on each `yield`. Thus the rewrite could look something like

```
def merge(xs,ys):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return ys
    elif len(ys) == 0:
        return xs
    else:
        a = (x for x in xs)     # or maybe iter(xs)
        b = (y for y in ys)     # or maybe iter(ys)
        list( merge_gen(a,b))
```

Now what's left is to re-implement your `merge` logic as `merge_gen` which expects two generators (or should that be *iterators*? do find out) as its input and generates the ordered stream of elements which it gets by pulling them one by one from the two sources as needed. The resulting stream of elements is converted back to list, as expected by the function's caller. No redundant copying will be performed.

If I've made some obvious Python errors, please treat the above as a pseudocode.

---

Your other option is to pre-allocate a second list of the same length and copy the elements between the two lists back and forth while merging, using *indices* to reference the elements of the arrays and mutating the contents to store the results.

Comment: "pre-allocate ... copy back and forth while merging..." - this is done in the [wiki example for top down merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation).

Answer (score 2):

I am no Haskell expert, so I might be missing something. Here's my best gamble:

Haskell list's are not state-aware. One implication of that is that lists can be shared. That make the action of halving leaner on memory allocations - To produce a 'drop n xs' you only have to allocate one list node (or whatever they are called in Haskell) and point it to the list element in the (n 'div' 2) + 1 node on the pre-halved list.
Note that 'take' is not able to do this little trick - it is not allowed to change a state of any node in the list, and hence it has to allocate new node object with equal values to the first n div 2 elements in the pre-halved list.

Now look at the python equivalent of that function - to halve the list, you use the list slicing:

```
def halve(xs):
    return (xs[:len(xs)//2],xs[len(xs)//2:])
```

Here you allocate two lists instead of one - in every level of the recursion tree! (I am also pretty sure that a list is a much more complex thing in python than the Haskell list, so probably allocation is slower, too)

What I would do:

1. Check my gamble - use the time module to see if your code spends too long allocating those lists, compared to the overall running time.
2. In case my gamble proved correct - avoid those allocations. A (Not very elegant, but probably fast) way to work around it - Pass a list, alongside with indices that indicate where each halve begin and where it ends. Work with offsets instead of allocating a new list each time. (EDIT:) You can avoid similar allocations as well - whenever you want to slice, pass an index to the begin\end of the new list.
3. And a last word - one of the requirements you've mentioned is keeping the functional approach. One can interpret that as keeping your code side-effect free.
   To do so, I'd define an output list, and store the elements you merge in it. Combined with the index approach, that will not change the state of the input list, and will produce a new sorted output list.

EDIT:
Another thing worth mentioning here: python lists are not singly linked-list, like Haskell lists. They are a data structure more commonly called [Dynamic Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array). This means that stuff like slicing, deleting an object from the middle of the list, etc. is expensive, since it has implication on ALL objects in the array. On the other hand, you are allowed to access an object at the i-th index in O(1). You should keep that in mind, it is closely related to the problem you came Up with.

Comment: I'm no Python anything, but since you say they aren't linked lists then probably `[xs[0]] + merge(xs[1:], ys)` will calculate the second list and then copy it whole to append to the first one (the singleton), thus leading to quadratic behavior.

Comment: True. Similar approach could solve that one as well - use an index, taking advantage of the random access provided by python lists.

Comment: by "use an index" you probably mean, we know the length of the result of `merge` since we know the lengths of its two arguments, so pre-allocate the list and then mutate its elements at progressive indices, right?

Comment: No, not really, although that is obviously an optimization.What I do mean: You could let merge take offset arguments - say a 'left_begin' and a 'left_end' arguments, and similar arguments for the "right side" list. The merge will than merge the [left_begin:left_end] left sublist, and the [right_begin:right_end] right_sublist, without allocating the sublists on each call

Comment: the problem is in how the output is built, not in how the input is read.

Comment: 'merge' function basically pick an element in the list, and push it to the output list, then recurse. What I meant in point three, was that you'd define an output list, an push elements to it on the fly, instead of allocating a new list in every level of the recursion. As you mentioned, preallocating is probably faster. Do you find this solves the problem? Also - Rereading that section (denoted 3.) looks unclear to me. Do you think I should edit?

Comment: Wow thank you for all this information! It is amazing! I am just trying to grasp it all :) I have now gotten a lot of new keywords , which I will go and read about. And I will try to optimize my list with all this new knowledge. I am so amazed. Thanks for the help all.!